How to install jsdom for all Node.js projects in Eclipse?
I'm currently using Eclipse 2020-06 with Node.js 14 and created a "General" project with a single .js file to test some Javascript code. I opened a command prompt and ran npm install jsdom@21.1.2 to install jsdom but this code:
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

... caused the following error when I ran the .js file:

Error: Cannot find module 'jsdom'

I cd-ed to the project folder and ran the install command again, now the code runs without any errors.
How do I install this specific version of jsdom in a way that all current and future Eclipse projects are going to find it too, without having to install it (= run the command) for every single project? There's no option to access the build path for this project ("no actions available") and so far I haven't been able to find any information about how to link to it with an environment variable or if there's a global setting for it in Eclipse.

Don't install your project modules globally or scoped to Eclipse (or any other IDE), even if you can do it with -g. Modules should be installed locally and saved into the project's package.json.
Reasons:

If you check your project into version control, which is the common case scenario for any moderately serious work, then when you pull down the project on another machine or try to get it working again at some point in the future, you'll have no idea which versions of all the packages will be necessary to run it.
If you want to run two projects at the same time that have different version requirements for a specific package, they'll fight each other and you may see confusing compatibility errors frequently, compounding as you add more projects. The possibility that two projects will have incompatible requirements that can't be resolved is almost inevitable once you try to manage 5 or 10 non-trivial projects over the course of a year or two. Migrating a single package.json through multiple version changes is difficult enough, much less doing it for all of your projects simultaneously.
It's common to need to remove a project's node_modules for various reasons. It's intended to be a disposable directory that isn't checked into version control. If you have one global node_modules and it needs to be recreated, or you're on a new machine, you have no package.json recipe you can use to rebuild it. package.json (and package-lock.json) is checked in to version control and is your source of truth for how to build each project. Once again, you risk your projects becoming unbuildable.

So avoid npm/dependency hell and do the normal thing of using a specific package.json for each project. Run npm i within each project folder to give it a node_modules folder tailored to each project's specific needs.
The one exception to this are certain common CLI tools that are intended to be installed globally, like @angular/cli. JSDOM doesn't fall into this category and should be installed on a per-project basis, without the -g flag.
In general, Eclipse is very much legacy, and I've never heard of it being used in any web development context. The standard environment for web projects at the time of writing is VSCode, which interacts perfectly naturally with the standard per-project package.json setup.
Your IDE shouldn't impose a runtime version or a legacy project structure. If it doesn't work smoothly with modern best practices, find one that does. Node 14 is also outdated and shouldn't be used for new development.

Can I do it for a specific Eclipse workspace instead? Eclipse 2020-03 is only compatible with up to Node.js 14, which in turn is only supported by up to jsdom 21.1.2 (v22 didn't work), so it's highly unlikely that I'm ever going to use a different version with it. For my Eclipse 2024 workspace I could then still get a more up-to-date version. My project hasn't even got a package.json file (or any packages), as it's only a general project (not e.g. "Dynamic Web Project") - because there doesn't appear to be a dedicated "JavaScript Project" option - with a single .js file that I'm running.

The modern standard is to use a package.json in every Node project so you can track your deps as I described in the post. Eclipse is basically a legacy IDE with a very poor reputation, so I see no reason to use it over VSCode and a standard modern development environment, unless you have a really compelling reason to differ from the standard. Why are you using Node 14 and Eclipse specifically, contrary to established practices?

Eclipse is simple, it works and does everything I need it to do (plus, it's open-source) and, as mentioned in my comment, this version is compatible with up to v14. I use VS with Unity and it feels cluttered and slow. But this wasn't my question. It's a "General" project (nothing "Node") with a JS file that uses Node.js to run. There aren't any other libraries, I'm only using this project to test my code before I move it to the big one. I don't want to have to install jsdom every time I use JS (or mess with an extra file just for that), so how do I install it for this specific Eclipse version?

Node 14 is fairly ancient, I wouldn't recommend developing on it. 22 is current. I've been a web dev for almost a decade and I've never heard of anyone using Eclipse for anything web-oriented, only crusty CS 101 Java projects for way outdated courses that haven't been updated since 2007. I agree though, IDEs are just IDEs so they shouldn't impose anything on the standard project structure (package.json in each project). They should just let you edit code and you'll run it with Node 22, so you shouldn't have to compromise the dev env just to meet your IDE's fickle needs.

Other answers show you the standard way to install packages globally, but take my word for it: you'll bring yourself a good deal of pain in the long run by installing all of your packages globally, as described in my answer. Installing locally is as simple as running a command: npm i jsdom.

As I said multiple times before, this version of Eclipse is only compatible with Node up to v14, which also limits what version of jsdom I can use (<v22). As I also already mentioned, I'm testing JS code with this "General" project. Jsdom is only needed to use e.g. DOMParser, which you otherwise don't get access to, unless you've got a full web project. In the end it doesn't matter if the libraries in this project are outdated, as long as the actual web project that is going to use the tested code is using fairly recent versions (that one doesn't even use Node.js).

You're right about one thing: That it's probably not a good idea to install jsdom in a way that makes it accessible to all versions of Eclipse (and any other IDE), unless it's easy to choose which version you want to use. That's why I want to install it just for this specific version of Eclipse (2020-06) because that's the version I plan on using to test future Javascript code as well (again: Testing semi-simple code, no need for fancy version control, library helpers,...).

I think there's some fundamental confusion. If you want to install this globally (I can't see any reason to), that decision is between you and node/npm, not your IDE. Your IDE just provides macros to run node and npm, it shouldn't prescribe anything about that or get in between you and doing whatever you want with npm and node. If you're encountering this much friction simply to install a package globally, there's your root problem. There should be no compatibility issues between Node and a particular IDE--this isn't even a thing in VSCode. With a normal dev env, this is a non-issue.

In other words, you appear to be struggling heavily to do something that's strongly discouraged and not even an actual problem to do in any other environment I've seen. You have two immediately-available solutions that seem more promising than continuing the fight: either don't try to do this in the first place, or pick an environment that makes it trivial, or (best yet) do both.

You can install any package for global access:
npm install jsdom -g

In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.

See the links below for more information:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack
NOTE 1: You still have to add jsdom entry to your package.json dependencies property in the distribution version of your package. Still, you can import the jsdom package from any script running through the NodeJS executable after the jsdom package is installed globally.
NOTE 2: You can write your package.json in a way that when you finalize your package through the npm pack command, the final file will not contain the dependecies (the third party packages). Your file will be smaller, but any other person installing your package will need to install the dependencies separately (that npm install does automatically reading the package.json file). You can also write the package.json in a way that the dependencies will be included in the final file, which will be larger (because it will contain the third party packages as well), but it can save your application/package in the case of any third party package being excluded from all repositories. Your package is standalone in this last case.

So install it first with my command wherever I want to keep it (e.g. "C:\Program Files\jsdom"), then run the .... -g command? Is there anything else I have to do, so that that specific Eclipse project finds it? I haven't got a package.json file and I'm also not using any packages (it's just a "general" project - because there are no "javascript" projects, only the full html ones - with a single .js file) but I did notice a warning about that while it was installing it: npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myuser\package.json'

@Neph, no. If you install the package using the npm install <package> -g then the package will be available anywhere on your system (NodeJS will always find it). There's no need for a package.json. BUT the package.json is useful when you intend to share your application/package. It hosts the dependencies of your application/package, in other words, it tells the NodeJS/NPM what are the third party packages that need to be installed for your application/package to work properly.

@Neph, also, if you install a third party package globally, that package itself will not be shipped/packed into your built package. If you not install the third party package globally, then that package will be included with your application/package built package, making the file larger (but can save your app if the package is removed from all repositories).

Is it possible to install multiple versions that way and tell a specific version of Node.js to use a specific version of jsdom? I think that one version per Eclipse install/workspace will work best, so I can keep the old version with my old Eclipse and a newer version with the new one, kind of like you can pick the Java version you want to use. I don't intend to share these small JS projects, they're only meant for testing code because it's faster than running the bigger web project every time (no need for jsdom in that one).

@Neph, Yes. NodeJS will search for modules in a fallback way... E.g.: /path/to/package. Node will search for any module/package at /path/to/package/node_modules, then if the module/package is not found there it will search at /path/to/node_modules, then /path/node_modules and so on until it reaches the root path, then the last place NodeJS will search is in the global node_modules path. So, you can install different versions of any package at each Eclipse worspace root directory. Just npm install the package with specified version in that Eclipse workspace root directory.

Let's say I've got two workspaces that contain a couple of projects each: 1. workspace2020 (for Eclipse 2020) and workspace2024 (for Eclipse 2024). If I run the install command from my question (with the extra -g) in workspace2020 (-> workspace2020\node_modules), then the project workspace2020\project1 should find it, correct? What about project workspace2024\project2, will that one also have access to that specific version of jsdom and if so, is there a way to limit it, so it stays within its own workspace?

@Neph, if you use -g then the package will not be installed in your workspace directory. You must install it without using -g. Run npm install specifying the version you want directly on workspace2020 and workspace2024 (each one with desired version). Then any project under workspace2020 will find the package version installed inside the workspace2020 directory. Then you do the same for workspace2024 with a different version as you need.

@Neph, Let's say you go to workspace2020 and install some package like npm install custom@2020 (after @ is the version to install). After this, custom will be installed in workspace2020/node_modules. It's done. Now workspace2020/project2020 can import the custom package/module. Node will look first for workspace2020/project2020/node_modules/custom, then it will look for workspace2020/node_modules/custom next (this last lookup will find the 2020 version).

I see, so I don't even need global install. Just to make sure: If I only install jsdom in workspace2020 but not in workspace2024, then any project in the former will be able to use jsdom, while every project in the latter won't see anything jsdom-related and will complain if I try anything like const jsdom = require("jsdom");, correct? Btw, there's a package-lock.json file in my project folder that installing jsdom there must have created (I didn't) and there are a lot of dependencies for registry.npmjs.org in it, including jsdom.

@Neph, yes, you're right. Now, about the package-lock.json, it is generated only by the npm command, not node itself. It's like a index of all modules/packages that affect the directory where package-lock.json is. See more here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-lock-json

Thanks, that's exactly what I need/want!

check your path when you download jsdom.
if the name of project is blabla , the path will be ...>...>blabla
or
try this`

npm i jsdom-global

 instead of this

npm install jsdom@21.1.2

`

I have to install this specific version because the latest isn't compatible with Node.js 14. check your path when you download jsdom - What do you mean? My code runs fine if I install it in the project folder (e.g. "Eclipse\Workspace-2020-06-Enterprise\blabla" but I want to install it in e.g. "C:\Program Files\jsdom", so it's independent of the projects, and I want to somehow tell Eclipse to use that one.

npm i jsdom-global doesn't install JSDOM globally (i.e. within multiple projects at once), it installs a package called jsdom-global locally. The name of the package happens to use the word "global", but that seems to be misleading you into thinking it's something other than a normal package. The purpose of this package is to expose JSDOM elements to the global scope within a single project, not what OP is asking about.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
